# How do I open a sample project in Xcode5?

Tags: xcode5

I want to open the `UICatalog` project in Xcode 5. I found it in the documentation viewer, but there is no button to allow me to open the project. In Xcode 4.6.3, there is an "Open Project..." button that allows me to quickly open the project in Xcode. How do I do this in Xcode 5?

**Update**

This screen shows very briefly

[image: Initial screen only shows for 1 second]

And then it switches to this screen

[image: Final screen, no "Open Project..." button]

I'm running Xcode 5 DP5 Version 5.0 (5A11365x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still open recent projects from the file menu just as in previous versions of Xcode. And in the same manner, you can still open projects from the "Welcome to Xcode" menu.

In Xcode hit Command-Shift-1 to open it, or Window->Welcome to Xcode. From here, you can select "Open other..." on the bottom right corner of the window.

Edit: Since after re-reading your post and realizing you're talking about the viewer for the actual Apple documentation in the "Help" menu, it doesn't appear anything has changed. Searching for "UICatalog" and clicking the result with the sample project brought me right to a screen with this at the top:

[image]

If you don't see this ^^^ I'd recommend making sure you update to the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: I only see that screen for like 1 second. I'm running Xcode5 DP5 on 10.8.4

Answer (score 0):

Just a regular open under File menu. The project files (.xcodeproj) should be available in the dialog box.

Comment: I'm talking about from within the documentation viewer.